# When is the loop space of a fibration a fibration? (Possibly up to homotopy equivalence)

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

On Page 409 of Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*, we see a sequence of maps

$\Omega B\to F\to E\overset{p}\to B$,

where $p:E\to B$ is a fibration and $F$ is the fiber $p^{-1}(b_0)$. $\Omega B\to F$ is a map that is homotopy equivalent to a fibration $F_i\to F_p$. He then applies the functor $\Omega$ to continue this sequence to the left:

$\ldots\to\Omega^2 B\to \Omega{F}\to \Omega{E}\overset{\Omega p}\to\Omega B\to F\to E\overset{p}\to B$.

My question is about the following statement, "Here, any two consecutive maps for a fibration, up to homotopy equivalence," that the author makes. Why is this true? For example, in the case of $\Omega F\to \Omega E\overset{\Omega p}\to \Omega B$, I don't believe that this is necessarily a fibration, but how can I prove that maybe this is a fibration up to homotopy equivalence? Any hints are appreciated!

Comment: Every map which is surjective on $\pi_0$ is a fibration up to (weak) homotopy equivalence; this is an extremely weak condition.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Do you have a source for this result? I would like to read up on this.

Comment: You can first replace the spaces involved with weakly homotopic CW complexes to make sure everything is nice, then take the mapping path space / mapping cocylinder: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cocylinder#definition_mapping_cocylinders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Suppose that $p:E\rightarrow B$ is a fibration over a well-pointed space $B$. Then for any locally compact space $K$, the map $p:Map_*(K,E)\rightarrow Map_*(K,B)$ is a fibration.

Here, $E,B$ are pointed spaces and the map $p$ preserves basepoints. By *well-pointed* we mean that the inclusion of the basepoint of $B$ is a closed cofibration. The *pointed* mapping spaces are to carry the compact-open topology.

The proof of the assertion runs by taking a lifting problem
\begin{array}{ccc}X &\rightarrow & Map_*(K,E)\\
\downarrow{} & &\ \downarrow \\
X\times I &\rightarrow& Map_*(K,B)
\end{array}
and considering the adjointed diagram
\begin{array}{ccc}K\times X &\rightarrow & E\\
\downarrow{} & &\ \downarrow \\
K\times X\times I &\rightarrow& B.
\end{array}
Because $p:E\rightarrow B$ is a fibration, the latter problem solves, and admits a diagonal lift $\Phi:K\times X\times I\rightarrow E$. However, we need to be a little careful about which solutions we will admit. Specifically, the adjoint of $\Phi$ will be a function $X\times I\rightarrow Map(K,E)$ which will be continuous, since $K$ is locally compact, but may not take values in the space of pointed maps.

For the adjoint of $\Phi$ to take values in the pointed mapping space we must ensure that the following condition is met
$$(\ast)\qquad\Phi(\ast,x,t)=\ast,\qquad \forall\, x\in X,t\in I.$$
This is the reason that we have assumed $B$ to be well-pointed, since this is sufficient to ensure that the fibration $p$ is *regular*, meaning that constant paths in $B$ can be lifted to constant paths in $E$. Because the arrow $K\times X\times I\rightarrow B$ satisfies the corresponding condition, regularity is therefore enough to ensure that a diagonal $\Phi$ exists satisfying condition $(\ast)$.

With those details sketched, the only thing to do is study the fibre of $p_*:Map_*(K,E)\rightarrow Map_*(K,B)$. This is the subspace
$$p_*^{-1}(\ast)=\{f\in Map_*(K,E)\mid p(f(K))=\ast\}=\{f\in Map_*(K,E)\mid f(K)\subseteq F\}\cong Map_*(K,F)$$
where $F=p^{-1}(\ast)$ is a closed subset of $E$.

Finally, aplying the above with $K=S^1$ we obtain a fibration sequence
$$\Omega F\rightarrow \Omega E\xrightarrow{p} \Omega B.$$